# Get computer name from IP-address

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network

I have the IP address of a computer on my network but is there a way that with the IP address I can find the name of computer?

For example, if I know the IP address is 192.154.23.60, can I use this IP from my Mac to see the name, such as Jacob's MacBook?

Answer (score 17):

From the `Terminal.app` (or equivalent) you can use the `host` command to show the network name of the computer. This returns the name even if it has all sharing settings turned off and thus not showing via `Finder`.

For example, in my network I get the following (where I know the IP-address and the first part of the returned name is the computer's name)

```
➜ ~ host 192.168.2.135

135.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer raspberrypi.private.lan.
```

It depends on the actual name of the computer if the network name is *exactly* the same, as in your example, I guess it would become `Jacobs-MacBook`.

Comment: This does not for for me for local servers: On my iPad an app creates a server under say http://192.168.0.4:8080, which I can access from my Mac, but neither `host 192.168.0.4` nor `arp 192.168.0.4` give me a name back.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: tried it, but did not work for me - using Angry IP scanner I did get the device name though

Answer (score 9):

Without further access to the host (e.g. ssh or ARD) and no service running on it (e.g. iTunes Music Sharing/File Sharing) you can't get the computer name based on the IP-address.

The computer name in macOS is **not** necessarily indentical to the hostname or the Bonjour name! You can simply check this with `scutil --get { ComputerName | LocalHostName | HostName }`. ComputerName is the user friendly name, LocalHostname is the Bonjour name - both also visible in System Preferences > Sharing - and HostName is the [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) of the device. The hostname is usually related to or used with DNS, NIS, hosts file or similar methods of name resolution. On a newly installed consumer system no hostname is set. ComputerName and LocalHostName are usually derived from the first user's name and the Mac model (e.g. Admin's iMac | Admins-iMac).

Without a name record for the remote Mac in your hosts file or on a DNS-server in your local or a public network neither of the tools mentioned in the other answers (arp, ping, host) can be used to resolve the hostname.

If a known Bonjour service is running on the remote Mac you can get the Computer and the Bonjour name of an IP in a two-step process by retrieving all hosts offering it with `dns-sd -Z _nfs._tcp local` (the example service here is NFS - other service names can be found [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)) and pinging all listed Bonjour names until you find the proper IP. As an GUI alternative you can use the [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/).

In some cases you can get a name similar to the Bonjour name by entering `smbutil status <IP>`. The name is the NetBIOS name which is the "all-caps and without allmost all special characters" version of the Computer/Bonjour name.

Answer (score 3):

In Terminal I would use `arp`

- First make sure you have sent at least one packet to this machine using ping.

  ```
  $ ping -c 1 2.2.2.12
    PING 2.2.2.12 (2.2.2.12): 56 data bytes  
    64 bytes from 2.2.2.12: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=0.981 ms
  ```
- Next `arp` that address.

  ```
  $ arp 2.2.2.12
    <host>.<domain> (2.2.2.12) at 0:1c:c4:f4:b8:c7 on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
  ```

Comment: You're just doing an extra step with the ping+arp combination. `arp` is just calling the same thing as `host` to return the hostname.

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score -2):

In Finder, go to your computer (which should be listed on the left sidebar under Devices). Then double-click on Network. This will show you all of the other computers on your network that are browsable.

Comment: That is not what he is asking, he is trying to find the host name from the ip address. just because a mahine is one the network does not mean that it is exposing afp, smb or netfs.

Answer (score -3):

Just Ping that ip address with -a option. It will show you the computer name.
Example `ping -a 192.168.0.1`

Comment: The `-a` flag means *audible* (or ring the bell).  It has nothing to do with hostnames.  Refer to the [man page for ping](https://ss64.com/bash/ping.html)

Comment: And the flag would have to be set directly after the command: `ping -a ...`

Comment: oh yeah sorry man.. Its ping -a ... some time hand makes mistake while mind not.

Comment: `ping -R -v ...` should do the trick on mac.